# Is Ubuntu Desktop still using mbr and not gpt?

Tags: partitioning, bootloader

i tried test install of Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.

Whatever i do (default, lvm, ZFS, by hand) its installing mbr partitions.

Disks is showing Partitioning Master Boot Record

Is that true?

How to select GPT to expand to > 2 TB in case?

Kind regards,

Bodo

Comment: Can use both depending how drive is partitioned.  If no other OS on drive, can change to GPT.  Can use gparted on live to change.

Comment: I use gparted to increase VMs from 100 GB (my) default to whatever i need.
With server version GPT is always used -> no problem.
Would be nice to do the same with desktop version and not loosing the installation.

Comment: I think its possible to use server version and if needed install desktop stuff afterwards.
Comments?

Answer (score 0):

### Rufus Settings for UEFI Only Ubuntu Install

If you want UEFI, setup installer USB drive as shown here.

Note **Partition scheme** and **Target system** for UEFI only install.

[image]

Comment: I just tried a 3 TB partition and Ubuntu is partitioning correct with GUID Partition table.    
I am using VMware and Rufus is a good idea but not very practical for VMs.   
Is it even possible to boot from USB?  
Any other idea how to start with 100 GB partition size and use GUID?

BTW: How do i add CR, 2 spaces does not work

Comment: Does System/Motherboard/Enable EFI work? I have converted a few .vdi to .img lately using: `VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW ubuntu.vdi ubuntu.img` perhaps you can create a UEFI mode Ubuntu on a USB, and convert it to .img then to vdi. (as a last resort).

Answer (score 0):

For me best practice to go is this way:

Install Ubuntu server with a 100 GB partition.
GPT is used without problems.
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install open-vmtools-desktop
Increased virtual graphics hardware from 4 GB to 16 GB to get higher resolutions.

Expanding partition size and resizing fs with boot from gparted iso should be no problem.

Thanks for your valuable hints @C.S.Cameron  @crip659